# The extension in image url is different from actual format

Tags: python, image, jpeg, heif, cvat

I downloaded an image from a url such as "https://www.xxxx.com/filename.jpeg. I expected that that image is a jpeg image whose format is acceptable for Computer Vision Annotation Tool (CVAT). However, it was saved as filename.heif or filename.jpeg.heif, so it causes an error when I tried to create a task with that image because heif format is not acceptable in CVAT. (CVAT automatically downloads images and create a task once I put image urls and submit them.)

I usually put more than 1000 image urls to create a task, and it is really hard to find invalid url or image among them.
Is there any way to find the "actual format" only by looking at the image url? Or can I just skip invalid urls in CVAT?
Thank you.

Comment: first check in some image vewer if you can open it. Maybe it is JPEG and you have to only remove extension. But if it is not JPEG then you will need some tool to convert `heif` to `jpeg` and send converted files

Comment: I have more than 1000K images so it is impossible to check all images in an image viewer. I hope there is a way to find 'actual format' by using only urls and filter invalid things.

Comment: url doesn't have to keep format - it can use whatever it likes. But you can use Python with module `pillow` to check if it can read file after downloading -and if it can't read it as JPEG then it is not JPEG.

Comment: theoretically when file is downloaded then server first sends headers with information about format - `MIME` - but server may use the fake format to force browser to download it instead of displaying.

Comment: it seems `pillow` has extension [pillow-heif](https://pypi.org/project/pillow-heif/) to read this format so you could use it to convert to jpg. But it would need to download images, convert them and upload on some server if you really want to use URLs in CVAT